# wp_mail sending emails in triplicate

Tags: wp-mail

I'm using `wp_mail()` in a page utilizing `insert_php`.

I'm constructing the mail with no extra headers, just a to email address, a subject and a message construct:

```
wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message );
```

I have changed the outgoing mail server using  [WP Mail SMTP](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/) (which does add specific headers that are correct for my use)

I am definately not looping the mail section there is no for loop period.
The whole code is between

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') {
```

as I am parsing some GET variables from a previous pages form

I have a favicon set up already.

I tried not using `wp_mail()` and use the raw PHP `mail()` but that failed completely!

Yet `wp_mail()` still sends each mail in triplicate and I have no ideas left!

Comment: post your code.

Comment: people that insert php in their content deserve all the hell they get, and should probably be thankful that it is not worse :(..... write proper code in proper way, code is not content and content is not code  :(

Comment: I agree with Mark. What you think will happen if you have three filters  doing something with your content ?